# Which way to fetch value from local.settings.json .NET6?

Tags: localhost, httpclient, settings, startup, appsettings

Could someone please explain which way, if any of these, is the preferred way of fetching values in Startup class from local.settings.json, C# .NET6. The startup.cs is for a function.

```
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["BaseEndpoints:RestIg"]);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BaseEndpoints:RestIg"));
            client BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetSection("BaseEndpoints:RestIg").Value);
```

In my local.settings.json I can have the value of BaseEndpoints:RestIg either inside or outside the values{}, not sure where I would want to place it?

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
"TimerInterval": "0 0 * * * *"
},
"BaseEndpoints": {
"RestIg": "https://myurl.com....etc.etc.etc" 
 }
}
```

[According to this dude](https://www.eugenechiang.com/2021/03/26/azure-function-get-environment-variable-using-local-settings-json/) Microsoft recommends this method because it works both locally with local.settings.json and in Azure.
i.e.
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BaseEndpoints:RestIg");`